# Combine two HybridDictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, hybrid

If I want to combine two regular dictionaries this will work:

```
var d3 = d1.Concat(d2).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

But `Concat` doesn't work for HybridDictionaries.

How can I combine two **HybridDictionaries**?

Answer (score 1):

Since [HybridDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary.aspx) only implements `IEnumerable`, extension methods that operate on `IEnumerable<T>` (e.g. `Concat`) do not apply.

Before being able to use `Concat` you would first have to transform your `HybridDictionary` objects into objects that implement `IDictionary<object, object>` (which in turn implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>`).

Let's say that your `HybridDictionary` objects are denoted `hybrid1` and `hybrid2`. You could then transform them like this prior to concatenation:

```
var nonHybrid1 = hybrid1.Keys.OfType<object>().ToDictionary(key => key, key => hybrid1[key]);
var nonHybrid2 = hybrid2.Keys.OfType<object>().ToDictionary(key => key, key => hybrid2[key]);
```

(Note that `hybrid1.Cast<KeyValuePair<object, object>>()` *does not* work, since the keys and values are not stored in this format internally.)

Now, with non-hybrid equivalents you could apply the regular LINQ operations like `Concat`:

```
var nonHybrid3 = nonHybrid1.Concat(nonHybrid2);
```

This will leave you with an object of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>`. To transform this into a `HybridDictionary` you would need to construct the new object and manually add the keys and values:

```
var hybrid3 = new HybridDictionary();
foreach (var kv in nonHybrid3) hybrid3.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
```